# Social media buttons in set into header

Tags: html, css, button, blogs

I am designing a blog by modifying an existing Jekyll theme where the header containing the title is one colour and the rest of the page another. I would like to insert a number of round icons (social networks etc.) in a line that are indented into the header. I feel it is easier to explain this with a picture:

[image]

where the blue dots are round icons or buttons. How can I achieve this in HTML/CSS?

EDIT:

AwokeKnowing gave me some tools to do what I want but they move when I resize my window.

This is what my page looks like on my 13" laptop screen:
[image]

but when I resize it on my 23" monitor I get:
[image]

I want it to look like my first image. This is my code:

HTML

```
<div>
<div class="s d">  <a href="mailto:?Subject=Mindfield-{{ page.title }}&amp;Body={{ page.url }}">
    <img src="/assets/images/mail-icon.svg" alt="Email" width=40px/>
    </a></div>
<div class="s e"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{site.domain_name}}{{page.url}}"
      onclick="window.open(this.href, 'facebook-share','width=580,height=296');return false;">
  <img src="/assets/images/Facebook-icon.svg" alt="Facebook" width=40px/></div>
<div class="s f"><a href="http://twitter.com/share?text={{page.title}}&amp;url={{site.domain_name}}{{ page.url }}"
      onclick="window.open(this.href, 'twitter-share', 'width=550,height=235');return false;">
  <img src="/assets/images/Twitter-icon.svg" alt="Twitter" width=40px/></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.s{position:absolute;top:216px;border-radius:50%;background:white;width:45px;height:45px;text-align:center;color:white}
.d{left:1200px}
.e{left:1255px}
.f{left:1310px}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's something to get you started

```css
.t{padding:20px;background:teal}
.con{position:relative;background:beige}
.c1{padding:20px}
.sc{position:relative;float:right;width:250px;}
.s{position:absolute;top:-10px;left:10px;border-radius:50%;background:blue;width:20px;height:20px;text-align:center;color:white}
.a{left:10px}
.b{left:40px}
.c{left:70px}
.d{left:100px}
.e{left:130px}
.f{left:160px}
```

```html
<div class="t">Title</div>
<div class="con">
  <div class="sc">
    <div class="s a">S</div>
    <div class="s b">O</div>
    <div class="s c">C</div>
    <div class="s d">I</div>
    <div class="s e">A</div>
    <div class="s f">L</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c1">Content</div>
  <div class="c1">Content</div>
  <div class="c1">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great thank you. But how do I stop their position moving if I resize the window?

Comment: @G_T what position do you want them to stay in? I don't see their position moving. I see them staying stuck to the left

Comment: I have updated my question to explain their position moving.

Comment: @G_T it looks like in your design you want them fixed on the right.  So I just put all the social items into a box and put it at the right.  Check it now. (maybe you can upvote since it's like another question)